# How Do I add a back button on a product page wordpress/woocommerce without code

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do i do this, is there a good plugin? can't find any. I have tried adding code but cannot and can't find anything. All i need is a back button, a back button on my product pages... help please!

Comment: where do you want the button to go?

Comment: above my products just on all my product pages

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "woocommerce_before_single_product" hook and add the button to shop URL

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'add_back_button_callback');

function add_back_button_callback() {
    $shop_url = get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) )
    echo '<a href="'.$shop_url.'">Back</a>';
}
```